# Issue with Cocoapod, macOS High Sierra and Firebase dependencies

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

Here is my issue, I recently updated to macOS High Sierra and Xcode 9.1.
I also installed cocoa pods. Then, I have a project, an IOS app which uses Firebase realtime database and Firebase storage.

So, I follow the guide provided by Firebase step by step but I always end with this issue when I try to build my project :

```
GTMSessionFetcher.framework: No such file or directory
```

or

```
GoogleToolboxForMac.framework : No such file or directory
```

I already read several similar posts on stackOverflow and I try different solutions provided but nothing works...
I tried :

- Clean the project
- Open .xworkspace
- Uninstall/Reinstall pods
- Delete Derived Data
- Close/Open workspace
- Restart Mac

Here is my pod file :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.1'

target 'Jack\'n\'Ferdi' do
 use_frameworks!
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

Pods are installed without errors when I launch pod install into the command line. I also try pod update. I am kind of desperate...

**Update**
When I create a new project from scratch and add those pods, it works perfectly ! The initial project is not from scratch. I got it from Github.

Comment: Are you opening the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj folder with Xcode?

Comment: For sure i am opening the xcwokspace file

Comment: Can you share a link to the initial project?