# Trying to add the Firebase SDK to an iOS project using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

When I try and build the project after configuring my podfile and installing the pod. I get this 
[image: error].

> This is the specific error message:
>   "/Users/jbmoss84/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lets_Travel-cgnhhmvnwassqgdzlgervlydkwfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Lets
>   Travel.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework: No such file or
>   directory?

I am using the Xcode workspace when I build.

I have tried cleaning my build folder, deleting my derived data, and anything else that I could think of. Nothing seems to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539494/issue-with-cocoapod-macos-high-sierra-and-firebase-dependencies

Comment: reinstall cocoapods  and just build your project not run. before this clear your derived data and quite xcode completely.

Comment: make sure you are opening your project with .xcworkspace file.

Comment: Have you added `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in your project root.

Comment: I have tried doing all of these things, still no luck.

Comment: The single quote in the project name might be causing problems ...

Comment: That was it!! I never even thought of that, it seems so obvious now . You are a hero sir.